# UIPasteboard in extension keyboard is not working if Allow Full Access toggle is off?

Tags: ios, settings, custom-keyboard, uipasteboard

In extension keyboard, `UIPasteboard` is not working if `Allow Full Access` toggle is **FALSE** in device settings.

Also I didn't found any documents specially on it. Anyone please write here their experience related to the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link for pasteboard functionality

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html